# Client Options? Azure VPN Gateway w/ OpenVPN (SSL) and Azure Active Directory Authentication

Tags: vpn, azure, gateway, entra-id, vpn-client

Are there other options for Azure VPN Client using Azure AD Authentication?

Tunnel Type:  OpenVPN (SSL)

Authentication Type:  Azure Active Directory

I've set up an Azure VPN Gateway using the following - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-tenant

The setup currently works and I'm able to connect to my Azure instance with access to my internal resources.  We are currently using the Azure VPN Client that has to be downloaded from the Windows 10 MS store.  We are running into an issue where there are some client systems that we do not have control over have their access to the MS Store disabled and cannot download the Azure VPN Client.  We have also explored OpenVPN but not sure if this is supported and only is available if we were using certificate-based authentication.

We really want to be able to VPN and use the Azure Active Directory for authentication.  In a complete windows environment, this seems doable and documented well but I have not been able to find a more vendor-agnostic VPN client to use in order to configure systems differently.  We may have to also test with Mac systems so something that can be used more universally would be optimal.

Please tell me there are other options and Azure VPN Client is not the only way to get Azure Active Directory authentication to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my question.  I guess I'll be going the RADIUS route.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/work-remotely-support#p2s

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, the best route would be RADIUS, however it is important to note that there is lack of support for 3rd party VPN clients. Microsoft only supports native VPN clients for each OS that is supported, with the exception of the OpenVPN client that Microsoft built (Azure VPN Client).

> **Can I use any software VPN client for point-to-site that supports SSTP and/or IKEv2?** No. You can only use the native VPN client on Windows for SSTP, and the native VPN client on Mac for IKEv2. However, you can use the OpenVPN client on all platforms to connect over OpenVPN protocol. Refer to the list of supported client operating systems.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/work-remotely-support#can-i-use-any-software-vpn-client-for-point-to-site-that-supports-sstp-andor-ikev2